# Will T-Sql SET parameters be reset with pooled .NET connections?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

The only SET parameter that I have found specific guidance for is SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL:

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION
>   LEVEL in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns
>   control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object
>   was invoked. For example, if you set
>   REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the
>   batch then calls a stored procedure
>   that sets the isolation level to
>   SERIALIZABLE, the isolation level
>   setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ
>   when the stored procedure returns
>   control to the batch.

What about other SET parameters, like `SET XACT_ABORT` or `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY`?  If you set those during a stored procedure (or a batch submitted from C#), will they go back to their previous values the next time the connection gets used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default (that is, unless you include "Connection Reset=false" in the connection string), .NET resets the connection with the `sp_reset_connection` stored procedure before reusing it; among other things it undoes any SET commands that have been issued since the connection was opened.

See [this article](http://www.sqldev.net/misc/sp_reset_connection.htm) for more details.

Comment: If you do any SQL tracing in ASP.NET applications it sticks out like a sore thumb, you'll see calls to sp_reset_connection all over the place. :)

Comment: That article doesn't render correctly in Firefox.  You have to select all to see the text.  But it's good info, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Transaction Isolation Level remains set for the rest of the current session.  That means that even after such a stored proc returns, if client cide calls another stored proc on the same connection (in the same session) that second proc will be executed under the same isolation level.

Comment: That's totally the opposite of what the documentation says.

Comment: @Eric, yes, I read only the body of question, missed the reference to .Net in the title, ... From SQL Books Online - "Only one of the isolation level options can be set at a time, and it remains set for that connection until it is explicitly changed."  sp_reset_connection is client-side behavior...